# scrollbar and multi-line not showing in textbox

Tags: wpf

Here is the code i wrote:

```
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,3,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="Comment here..."                                                
                        FontSize="12"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        Height="35"
                        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text.IsEmpty, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBox Margin="0" Background="#AAFFFFFF"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="FilterTextBox"
                        Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        MinLines="2" 
                        MaxLines="2"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                             
                        MaxLength="{Binding MaxLength}"
                        Height="35">
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
```

This works as desired if i enter any letters it removes comments here... but problem is i have set textbox as MinLines = 2 and scrollbar visible but both are not working. I can only enter text in one line. Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this in wpf?

Comment: try this http://adnan8t2p.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/wpf-multiline-textbox.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TextBox.TextWrapping Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textwrapping%28v=vs.100%29) is `TextWrapping.NoWrap` by default. Set it to `Wrap` or `WrapWithOverflow` and it should work.

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"
```